# How to cut down GC_CONCURRENT actions?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm writting an app for android to log all sensor data, but after variable time period app keeps crashing on sensorservice died log, then smartphone seems to reset itself.
My logcat looks like this:

```
I/sensorLis﹕ added MPL Accelerometer
I/sensorLis﹕ added MPL Gyroscope
I/sensorLis﹕ added Corrected Gyroscope Sensor
I/sensorLis﹕ added MPL Magnetic Field
I/sensorLis﹕ added MPL Gravity
I/sensorLis﹕ added Gravity Sensor
I/sensorLis﹕ added MPL Rotation Vector
I/sensorLis﹕ added Rotation Vector Sensor
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 509K, 7% free 9687K/10375K, paused 6ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 7% free 9674K/10375K, paused 9ms+1ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 7% free 9676K/10375K, paused 13ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 391K, 7% free 9676K/10375K, paused 4ms+1ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 406K, 7% free 9677K/10375K, paused 5ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K, 7% free 9678K/10375K, paused 6ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 7% free 9681K/10375K, paused 1ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 412K, 7% free 9680K/10375K, paused 9ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 407K, 7% free 9679K/10375K, paused 3ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 7% free 9681K/10375K, paused 6ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 7% free 9689K/10375K, paused 8ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 422K, 7% free 9680K/10375K, paused 4ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 393K, 7% free 9680K/10375K, paused 4ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 7% free 9690K/10375K, paused 6ms+6ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 420K, 7% free 9682K/10375K, paused 5ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 409K, 7% free 9680K/10375K, paused 4ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 399K, 7% free 9680K/10375K, paused 6ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 393K, 7% free 9682K/10375K, paused 6ms+2ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 412K, 7% free 9680K/10375K, paused 5ms+3ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 7% free 9681K/10375K, paused 6ms+3ms
W/Sensors﹕ sensorservice died [0x1e56260]
I/ActivityThread﹕ Removing dead content provider: settings
E/InputQueue-JNI﹕ channel '41d3d498 com.edu.jirka.naviin/com.edu.jirka.naviin.Navin (client)'
```

And at the time of crash i have just several instaces of the `SensorDataSaver` running as listeners for like 5 to 90 seconds.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Jirka on 8/21/2015.
 *
 * - designed for sensor data saving to files on external storage
 */

public class SensorDataSaver implements SensorEventListener{

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private BufferedWriter bw;
    private Sensor mSensor;

    /**
     * class designed to save data of any 3D individual sensor.
     *
     * @param ma - activity for SensorManager, Resources access
     * @param header - basic info about sensor
     * @param ssr - sensor to by listen to
     */
    public  SensorDataSaver(Activity ma, String header, Sensor ssr, File sampleDir) {
        mSensor = ssr;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) ma.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        try {
            // Header creation
            File mFile = new File(sampleDir, mSensor.getName().replace(" ", "_") + "_Data.txt");
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mFile));
            bw.write(header);
            bw.append("Timestamp X_axis Y_axis Z_axis Current Accuracy\n");
        }catch (NullPointerException n){
            Log.e("File_Err","Fault during creating output file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("BuffW_Init","Fault during BufferedWriter init");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void startCollecting(int del){
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mSensor,del);
        Log.i("sensorLis","added " + mSensor.getName());
    }

    public void finishCollecting(){
        // deploy listener
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        // close file
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("BuffW_Close","Fault during BufferedWriter closing");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /* onSensorChanged method of SensorListener */
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
        try {
            bw.append(se.timestamp + " " + se.values[0] + " "
                    + se.values[1] + " " + se.values[2] + " " + se.sensor.getPower() + " "
                    + se.accuracy);
            bw.newLine();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("BW_APPEND",mSensor.toString() + " fault during appending sensor changes");
        }
    }

    /* onAccuracyChanged method of SensorListener */
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        /* accuracy changes omitted due to accuracy logging in onSensorChanged
        try {
            bw.append("Accuracy " + sensor.getName() + " -> " + accuracy);
            bw.newLine();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("BW_APPEND", "Fault during appending accuracy changes");
        }*/
    }


}
```

So have you any idea how cut down GC actions and keep sensorservice from dying?
I would need to be able to log sensor data for at least 10 minutes.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be asking two unrelated questions: how to reduce GC activity, and how to keep sensorservice from dying. The latter seems more important, but isn't in the subject of your question. Do you know why sensorservice is dying?

Comment: I dont know exactly but I'm trying to log sensor data of approx. 6 sensors with `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`, so i suppose incoming messages to sensorService might cause it.

Answer (score 1):

> So have you any idea how cut down GC actions and keep sensorservice from dying?

I would start by cleaning up `onSensorChanged()`, since that will be called a lot, and get rid of the memory-churning string concatenation:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
    try {
        bw.append(se.timestamp);
        bw.append(" ");
        bw.append(se.values[0]);
        bw.append(" ");
        bw.append(se.values[1]);
        bw.append(" ");
        bw.append(se.values[2]);
        bw.append(" ");
        bw.append(se.sensor.getPower());
        bw.append(" ");
        bw.append(se.accuracy);
        bw.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("BW_APPEND", mSensor.toString() + " fault during appending sensor changes", e);
    }
}
```

Beyond that, use development tools to determine where you are spending your time and your RAM. Android Studio can help you track CPU usage and memory allocations, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I improved it a lot with StringBuilder, but still can find out how to stop sensorService from dying.